# Nodejs: express call class method return undefined `this`

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

This is my code:

bannerController:

```
class bannerController extends generalController {
  constructor() {
    super(BannerService);
  }
}

export default new bannerController();
```

generalController:

```
export default class generalController {
  public service: any;

  constructor(service: any) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  public async status(req: Request, _res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> 
  {
    console.log(this)
  }
}
```

router:

```
router.patch(
  '/banner/:id/status',
  bannerController.status,
);
```

This line `console.log(this)` return `undefined`

If I change it to `bannerController.status.bind(bannerController)` work fine.

But I don't want to use call, bind and ...

Comment: if you want the correct `this` - then you have to use `call`, `bind`, or `apply`.

Comment: there are typescript decorators and other packages that help with this as well - but they use `call`, `bind` and `apply` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-bind

Comment: Be sure to name you classes starting with capital letters. It's nothing to do with you problem directly, but that would be the right practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach would be giving your class a method that *returns* the middleware function, as illustrated by the following code (Javascript, not Typescript, sorry):

```js
class generalController {
  ...
  statusMiddleware() {
    return async function(req, _res, next) {
      console.log(this);
    }.bind(this);
  }
}
router.patch(
  '/banner/:id/status',
  bannerController.statusMiddleware()
);
```

Comment: bind makes me repeat the bannerController

Comment: So you don't mind using `.bind(this)` like in my edited answer?